# Asp.net open a new tab from code behind

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I'm having trouble getting a new tab to open using window.open from an asp button.  It's inconsistent, when I call it from a jquery dialog it's fine, if I try to use `ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript` it opens a new window instead of a tab.  I'm just wondering what the difference is.

Also calling a function from OnClientClick works fine.  I'd like to use just OnClick so I can validate in code behind.

This creates a new window instead of a tab each time.

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "script", "window.open('mypage.aspx?NewTab');", true);
```

Comment: By new tab, you just mean a new tabbed window in your browser, rather than a popped out instance of a tab?

Comment: Can you show code that you use when you call it from a jquery dialog?

Comment: Yes, just a new tab, not a pop out.  The jquery dialog is using the same code just from a function at the bottom of the page.  

function newtab(){ window.open('mypage.aspx?NewTab'); }

Comment: I am pretty sure that whether a new window opens as a tab or not is a using setting on pretty much all browsers, and there is no way to control it from javascript.

Comment: In JavaScript: `var win=window.open(url, '_blank'); win.focus();` works to create a new tab. Change the URL to your need. Note: `url` is a String, so wrap the URL in quotations.

Comment: I think @Jason is specifically speaking about what ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript does differently than just doing it clientside. I too am curious about this because I had the same issue when working with an asp:button and trying to make things open in a new tab. I just chalked it up to asp:buttons not being a good solution to modern client-driven development. I ended up just doing it all client side and turning the asp:button into a regular link.

Comment: Ahh so he is. That'll teach me for not reading the question more carefully.